# DataView parameter DefaultValue

Tags: data-view-web-part, default-value

Please help, what should I set to the default value in DVWP filter parameter if it should be ISO8601 date format of the actual date?

It only works now if I manually enter current date like 
    `<ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="Control(DropDownList1)" DefaultValue="2013-01-02T12:00:00Z"/>`

I am also wondering if the DVWP is linked to a drop-down list, even if the dropdown shows actual date, the filter is working only if the entire page is reposted / so only once I change the drop-down selection.

So the other question is if there is any possibility without using scripts to postback value automatically once the page is initialized?
I have a similar problem I think which I could read here: 
[Dynamically setting Default Value in ParameterBinding through Javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22012/dynamically-setting-default-value-in-parameterbinding-through-javascript), still waiting resolution.

Comment: Any update? It seems to be an easy question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: How can I bounty if there is no bounty button? I have asked a question almost a week ago and cannot see any response - is it the normal way asking the same question again and again?

Comment: If you are not getting any answers to your question you might consider trying to improve the question to increase the chance of a response. There is further advice in our FAQ: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Got it, thanks for the suggestions, and the reply. Let me check how it works and get back soon, friends!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, I have taken the part out that is relevant to you and posted the link:

SharePoint works with default dates in the `ISO8601` format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`. When you  create a `DVWP`, by default SPD will get the date field value using “`ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@datefiled), 1033,5)`”.   This is hard code, you can’t manage them globally.

So please check your DVWP for date fields, make sure you have used this kind function. For more information, please refer [this](https://autosponge.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/ddwrt-formatdate-and-formatdatetime/) or [this](https://blog.metrostar.com/2009/11/13/performing-datetime-calculation-in-dvwp-using-xslt).

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83bd5949-106e-47ac-8375-692f3c474db6/date-format-in-dvwp-looking-strange-with-quotzquot-at-the-end?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Hi @almostSharepointMaster
I tried this tag:
 `code`<ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="Control(DropDownList1)" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>`code`
alternatively as described above:
 `code`<ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="Control(DropDownList1)" DefaultValue=ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(CurrentDate), 1033,5)/>`code`

However it does not properly return the actual date.

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: both tag `code`s return empty row for the data view webpart. However, it should return all the rows where the date is equal or later than CurrentDate

Comment: It only works if I manually enter current date like `code` <ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="Control(DropDownList1)" DefaultValue="2013-01-02T12:00:00Z"/> `code`